# Run commands with quotes in shell

Tags: bash, sh

How do I run this grep command with piping in a bash script?

```
$email is an email address
$subject is a string "82\% Internet Quota Used\!"

grep "$(grep "to=<$email.*status=sent" /var/log/mail.log | cut -d ":" -f 4 )" /var/log/mail.log | grep -c "$subject”
```

Comment: Where is $subject? What is $(grep ?

Comment: When you copy that code into a bash script, what is the error that you get?

Comment: The last character is not " . That's causing the issue. See my answer below. it has been tested and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
grep "$(grep "to=<$email.*status=sent" /var/log/mail.log | cut -d ":" -f 4 )" /var/log/mail.log | grep -c '$subject'
```

It works at my end. 
My test.log looks like below.

```
test

dsfs
sd
ds
test
asd
asd
testasdasd
```

Copy the below code in a file called as test.sh and run it as ./test.sh

```
subject=test
count=$(grep "$(grep "$subject" test.log | cut -d ":" -f 4 )" test.log  | grep -c "$subject")

echo $count
```

Output :

```
Mayur:~ mayurnagekar$ ./test.sh 
3
```

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I want to run this code inside a bash script. I want to capture the return value into a variable.

Comment: I tried this in a bash script now. It works. Copying the code above.

Comment: Cool! :) You may want to chose this answer as correct one.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear why you are attempting to grep a second time on `message-id` as it loses the quality of being limited to `sent` messages. For example, you gather the sent `message-id`'s with the following

```
grep "$email.*status=sent" mail.log | cut -d ":" -f 4
C6625F3A4D
E3868F3A5C
20A2DF3A4D
...
```

You then `grep` again on each `message-id` again which returns **all** log entries for each `message-id` losing the limit to the entries containing `status=sent`. You then `grep` a **3rd** time to limit to the entries containing your `$subject` line.

If the user (`$email`) is over quota, why not retain the limit for the `status=sent` and provide that as your `count` of messages over the quota? Doing so, you can eliminate all but one `pipe` by simply using `wc -l` (lower-case `L`) instead of a cut, second and third `grep`:

```
grep "$email.*status=sent" mail.log |  wc -l
```

If you truly need the `$subject` limit, please post a snippet of your log showing how the `$subject` line is included in the entry. (you can `xxxxx@xxxx.xx` each of the addresses, etc.) To limit on over quota messages for a unique users, it would be done similar to:

```
grep "$subject.*status=sent" mail.log | grep "$email" | wc -l
```

**NOTE:** you may need to switch the order of the query in the first grep to `"status=sent.*$subject"` depending on how the entries are shown. (that's why we need to see a snippet)

Comment: I want to check whether an email is sent with the same subject.

Comment: I understand, I'm just looking at it and thinking it can be done more efficiently than with `grep, grep, cut, grep`.

Comment: +1 for not answering the actual question (just bad quotes!) but for answering the more important question about why such a convoluted pipeline and giving a more elegant answer.

Comment: Sorry, can anyone give a more elegant and efficient answer?

Comment: Have you tried `grep "$subject.*status=sent" mail.log | grep "$email" | wc -l` ?  If you have trouble with that, let me know and post a couple of line of your `mail.log` so I can see how the quota message is integrated into the subject.